# SQL ORDER BY a sequence column then all records in group, then resume next sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

I have these two columns in a table (SEQ, GROUP_CODE) with the following data (example):

```
SEQ, GROUP_CODE
---------------    
1, 2
2, 2
3, 2
4, 5
5, 2
6, 3
7, 5
```

I need this to sort like this:

```
SEQ, GROUP_CODE
---------------    
1, 2
2, 2
3, 2
5, 2
4, 5
7, 5
6, 3
```

Basically, use the sequence to start the ordering and "drain" all group records before moving on to the next sequence before draining its group and so on. I know I could do this with a stored procedure using a cursor, but would like to see if this can be done with an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions in `order by`.  So:

```
order by min(seq) over (partition by group_code),
      seq
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I'm attempting to use this order by clause in a UNION ALL but keep getting the error:  Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator. Seq and group_code columns are in both SELECT LISTs of each statement in the UNION ALL. Alias column names or column indexing doesn/t work. - Kurt

Comment: @cantelopehead . . . Ask another question and include the complete query.